# Creating custom table view header with search controller iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to create a custom header view for my `UITableView`. This custom header comprises a search bar and a button. `Xib` image given below: [image]

In code, I am doing the following while configuring the `searchController` in `MyViewController`:

```
let searchHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SearchHeaderView",
                owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! SearchHeaderView

            searchHeaderView.searchBar = searchController.searchBar

            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchHeaderView
```

The problem is that when I tap on the search bar it does not animate and cover the navigation bar. It just behaves as a normal search bar. Plus it does not carry out any search at all (`updateSearchResultsForSearchController` is not called even though delegate is set). In contrast if I just add the `searchController's` search bar as the header view, then the search bar animates to the top when active and the search functionality runs fine.

However, I cannot use that as I need the button right next to the search bar.